# Why this two surfaces have one end?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, surfaces

I want to prove that the infinite-holed torus and the infinite-jail cell window have one end but the doubly infinite-holed torus doesn't, my definition of one end is the following:

> A locally compact (not compact) space $X$ has one end if for every compact $C \subset X$ there is a compact $K$ such that $C \subset K \subset X$ and $K^{c}$ is connected.

But the thing is that I don't know how to wave my hands here. Can someone help me with this issue?

> The pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your definition of the infinite-holed torus is, but it sounds as if you're meant to embed $X$ in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ and let $K$ be the intersection of $X$ with a sufficiently large closed ball.

Comment: May be I should include a picture, just a second :)

Comment: Ready :) does this clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Follow Andrew's suggestion: First, embed $X$ inside $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, any compact $C \subset X$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that you may find a large closed ball $B$ containing $C$. (For the infinite torus you also want to enlarge the ball so that it contains the entire "end" as well as $C$.) Finally take $K = B \cap X \supset C$.

The problem with the doubly infinite torus is that $K^c$ will always be disconnected for any compact $C$ such that $C^c$ is disconnected.

Comment: Is it the same for the jail ?

Comment: @user162343 yes, because removing a ball from the jail doesn't disconnect it.

Comment: So this is a wave hand proof right ?

Comment: @user162343 It's a bit handwavy yes, but I think it's pretty convincing.

Comment: Right :) do you something in algebra ?

Comment: Why we require that $B$ covers the entire "end" if we don't know that is has one? :)